# I need help in gdb debugging firefox 17.0.11

Tags: debugging, firefox, gdb, rhel5

I have an application based on customized firefox 17.0.11. I am facing issues with it. I want to debug it using gdb. However, I am not able to get debug symbols for version 17.0.11. I yum installed 17.0.10, but when I run with gdb it is unable to find any debug symbols. I tried the following, but no benefit:

1. Copying the /usr/local/debug/firefox folder to location of firefox binary
2. I checked in the installed files (`rpm -ql firefox-debuginfo`), but there is no firefox/firefox-bin.debug file there.

So, can someone please help me on where to get the debug symbols and what is the right way to install on on RHEL5?

Comment: Did you get 17.0.11 from a Red Hat repository? I don't have access to Red Hat, but the latest in the 17.x line that I can find in the CentOS 5 repositories is 17.0.10.

Comment: Downloaded from https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Comment: The debuginfo has to come from a build that used the same source code and build options as the non-debuginfo binary. Maybe Mozilla provides one, but it isn't in the directory tree at that URL you mentioned. You could build firefox from source. Or, since you have Red Hat's 17.0.10, you can download and install the debuginfo for that with `sudo debuginfo-install firefox-17.0.10`. If you don't have the `debuginfo-install` program, you can get it by installing the `yum-utils` package.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I don't know which repository to configure, such that sudo debuginfo-install firefox-17.0.11 would be possible.
The alternative I am currently looking is download the source code for 17.0.11 and build it with debug symbols. However, this process is quite tedious and facing blockers on this as well.
It would be great if could get the repository from where to download the 17.0.11 debug symbols.